# Search enging using java ee (.jsp .java bean.java)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Hi im wondering how to make a simple search engine without using the database

I have 3 pages StudentSearch.jsp, StudentSearchController.java StudentSearchBean.java

I dont know where to start using simple mvc in java. Thank you.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
HttpSession session = request.getSession();


try{

    String  pro_code  = request.getParameter("pro_code");
    String  name  = request.getParameter("name");
    String  price  = request.getParameter("price");

    ArrayList pList = null;
    ArrayList proList = new ArrayList();
    pList  = new ArrayList();

    pList.add(pro_code + ("0000001"));
    pList.add(name + ("sample"));
    pList.add(price + ("1000"));
    proList.contains(pList);

    request.setAttribute("proList" +  session, proList);        

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/studentSearch.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);

} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

below is my jsp, hope i added some information (sorry for my bad english).

```
<%
int count=0;
String color = "blue";

if(request.getAttribute("proList")!=null) {

ArrayList plist = (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("proList");
    Iterator lst = plist.iterator();

    while(lst.hasNext())
    {
        if((count%2)==0)
        {
            color="yellow";
        }
        else
        {
            color="brown";
        }
        count++;
        ArrayList proList = (ArrayList)lst.next();

        %>

<%=proList.get(0)%>
<%=proList.get(1)%>
<%=proList.get(2)%>

<%
    }
}

%>



SEVERE: Error starting static Resources java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\Users\cire\Documents\softdev-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\StrutsStarter does not exist or is not a readable directory
at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4894)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5074)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1568)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1558)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I suggest you start by reading this book, [Head First Servlets and JSP](http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Servlets-JSP-Certified/dp/0596005407) you will make this search engine before finishing the 4th chapter.

Comment: i don't have money to buy this book, i have created 3 pages but i dont know what is wrong with my codes, it doesnt show up in the web browser

Comment: Can you tell us what the error is? If in doubt post the exception and the URL you requested

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that the exception you have here is nothing todo with the code. It appears to be an issue on server start.

But on the code front

```
proList.contains(pList);
```

this just test that `proList` contains object `pList` it won't

If you want all the elements of `pList` in `proList` then:

```
proList.addAll(pList);
```

If you want to add `pList` as a element to `proList` then:

```
proList.add(plist);
```

The next issue is

```
request.setAttribute("proList" +  session, proList);
```

What are you trying todo here? I would guess you might what to do:

```
request.setAttribute("proList", proList);
```

In fact you might want to rethink most of the code above and go for something like:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String  pro_code  = request.getParameter("pro_code");
    String  name  = request.getParameter("name");
    String  price  = request.getParameter("price");

    // do something usefull with the parameters here

    // expose the results to the jsp like so:
    request.setAttribute("pro_code", pro_code);  
    request.setAttribute("name", name);  
    request.setAttribute("price",price); 
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/studentSearch.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

note lack of `catch(Exception e)`

Comment: we need a bit more information, we can barely understand your program, it is really difficult to provide any meaningful answers. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and then comeback and redo your question (or ask another)